# A lot of white space below webpage

Tags: html, css

I have getting lots of whitespace at the bottom of my page. I don't understand which div is causing this problem. Can someone please point out at my mistake.

I have spend hours trying to solve this problem and seen similar posts, but nothing seems to work out. Kindly someone solve this, as it is 4AM, and I don't have any stamina left. Thanks

```css
.blackup{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 background: #000000;
}
.down
{
 height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.down:after
{/*   z-index: 1; */
 bottom: 0;
 background: black;
 content: '';
 height: 25px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: skewY(-19deg);
 width: 100%;
}
.purple
{
 height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.purple:after
{/*   z-index: 1; */
 margin-top: 4px;
 bottom: 0;
 background: #513a82;
 content: '';
 height: 25px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: skewY(-19deg);
 width: 100%;
}
.down2
{
 height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.down2:after
{/*   z-index: 1; */
 margin-top: 8px;
 bottom: 0;
 background: black;
 content: '';
 height: 25px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: skewY(-19deg);
 width: 100%;
}
.white
{
 height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.white:after
{/*   z-index: 1; */
 margin-top: 8px;
 bottom: 0;
 background: white;
 content: '';
 height: 392px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;top: 0;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: skewY(-19deg);
 width: 100%;
}
.grad1
{
 margin-left: 26px;
 margin-bottom: 431px;
 margin-top: -754px;
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#6b5773, #799DB7);
 width: 1128px;
 height: 1400px;
 position: relative;
 clip-path: polygon(12% 0%,35% 0%,35% 37.8%, 12% 44.2%);
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.text1
{
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1807px;
    font-size: 71;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 177px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
}
.text2
{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 25px;
 font-size: 71;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 177px;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 transform: scaleY(2.1);
}
.text3
{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 48px;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 177px;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 transform: scaleY(2.5);
}
.wb
{
 margin-left: 178px;
    margin-bottom: 41px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    background: white;
    width: 142px;
    height: 132px;
    position: relative;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 4%, 0 4%);
}
.p1
{
  font-family: monospace;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -147px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 177px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.grad2
{
 margin-top: -456px;
 margin-left: 1134px;
 height: 127px;
 width: 199px;
 position: relative;
 background:#31302e;
 opacity:0.8;
}
.grad2:after
{
 bottom: 0;
 background: inherit;
 content: '';
 height: 285px;left: 0;
 position: absolute;right: 0;
 top: 0;transform-origin: top right;
 transform: skewY(-18deg);
 width: 100%;
}
.text4
{
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -104px;
 margin-left: 1146px;
 color: white;
 transform: scaleY(2.1);
}
.text4 a
{
 text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
 transform: scaleY(2.1);
}
.text5
{
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 24px;
 margin-left: 1146px;
 color: #318ECB;
 transform: scaleY(2.2);
}
.text5 a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 37px;
 color: #318ECB;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 transform: scaleY(2.2);
}
.p2
{
  font-family: monospace;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 1146px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.box1
{
 bottom: -519px;
 margin-left: 154px;
 width: 280px; 
 position: relative; 
 background-color: transparent;
}
.box1:after
{
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: #553e86;
 content: '';
 height: 434px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: skewY(-19deg);
 width: 100%;
}   
.box2
{
  bottom: -399px;
    margin-left: 533px;
    width: 280px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.box2:after
{
 bottom: 0px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#472965, #3789c1);
 content: '';
 height: 434px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: skewY(-19deg);
 width: 100%;
} 
.box3
{
 bottom: -279px;
    margin-left: 903px;
    width: 280px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.box3:after
{
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: #553e86;
 content: '';
 height: 434px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0;
 transform-origin: top left;
 transform: skewY(-19deg);
 width: 100%;
} 
.t1
{
 z-index: 2;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 634px;
    margin-left: 177px;
    color: white;
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
}
.t1 a
{
 z-index: 2;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
    font-weight: bold
}
#d1
{
 z-index: 2;
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 177px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.4);
}
#p1
{
 z-index: 2;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 35px;
 margin-left: 177px;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 transform: scaleY(1.4);
 line-height:1.3;
}
.t2
{
 z-index: 2;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -313px;
    margin-left: 603px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
}
.t2 a
{
 z-index: 2;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
    font-weight: bold
}
#d2
{
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 608px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.4);
}
#p2
{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 35px;
 margin-left: 563px;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 transform: scaleY(1.4);
 line-height:1.3;
}
.t3
{
 z-index: 2;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -321px;
    margin-left: 931px;
    color: white;
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
}
.t3 a
{
 z-index: 2;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
    font-weight: bold;
}
#d3
{
 z-index: 2;
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 931px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.4);
}
#p3
{
 z-index: 2;
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 39px;
    margin-left: 931px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.4);
    line-height: 1.3;
}
.b1
{
 bottom: -258px;
    margin-left: 176px;
    width: 231px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.b1:after
{
 z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    height: 116px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: skewY(-19deg);
    width: 100%;
} 
.b2
{
 bottom: -139px;
    margin-left: 557px;
    width: 231px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.b2:after
{
 z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    height: 116px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: skewY(-19deg);
    width: 100%;
} 
.b3
{
 bottom: -45px;
    margin-left: 878px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 231px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.b3:after
{
 margin: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: black;
    content: '';
    height: 194px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: skewY(-19deg);
    width: 100%;
} 
.blackborder{
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: 301px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 175px;
    background: #000000;
} 



/*.modern
{
 font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 360px;
    margin-left: 931px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transform: scaleY(1.5);
    font-weight: bold;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="blackup"></div>
     <div class="flyer"><img src="E:\Software House\Flyer\a.jpg" width="100%"></div>
     <div class="down"></div>
     <div class="purple"></div>
     <div class="down2"></div>
     <div class="white"></div>
       <div class="grad1"></div>
       <div class="text1">THE</div>
       <div class="text2"><b>FLYER</b></div>
       <div class="text3">BRAND</div>
       <div class="wb"></div>
       <div class="p1">Dolor sit amet<br>consectetuer a<br>depising elit.</div>
       <div class="grad2"></div>
       <div class="text4"><a href="#">LOREM</a></div>
       <div class="text5">
        <a href="#">IPSUM</a>
       </div>
       <div class="p2">Dolor sit amet<br>
        consectetuer a<br>
        depising elit.
       </div>
       <div class="box1"></div>
       <div class="box2"></div>
       <div class="box3"></div>
       <div class="t1">
        <a href="#">CORPORATE</a>
       </div>
       <div id="d1">DESIGN</div>
       <div id="p1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the<br>printing and typesetting industry. Lorem<br>Ipsum has been the industry's standard<br>dummy text ever since the 1500s, when<br>an unknown printer took a galley of type<br>and scrambled it to make a type specimen<br>book. It has survived not only five , but<br>also the leap into electronic typesetting.</div>
       <div class="t2">
        <a href="#">SUPPORT</a>
       </div>
       <div id="d2">DESIGN</div>
       <div id="p2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the<br>printing and typesetting industry. Lorem<br>Ipsum has been the industry's standard<br>dummy text ever since the 1500s<br>when an unknown printer took a galley<br>of type and scrambled it to make a type<br>specimen book.</div>
       <div class="t3">
        <a href="#">MANAGEMENT</a>
       </div>
       <div id="d3">DESIGN</div>
       <div id="p3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the<br>printing and typesetting industry. Lorem<br>Ipsum has been the industry's standard<br>dummy text ever since the 1500s, when <br>an unknown printer took a galley of type<br>and scrambled it to make a type specimen<br>book. It has survived not only five , but<br>also the leap into electronic.</div>
       <!-- <div class="modern">MODERN</div> -->
       <div class="b1"></div>
       <div class="b2"></div>
       <div class="b3"></div>
       <div class="blackborder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your div with class `grad1` literally has a `margin-bottom` of over 400px. Fixing this would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues seem to come from your `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, and `height` in the `grad1` class as well as the `margin-top` in the `text1` class. Removing those seems to fix the white space at the bottom issue. Also, I would refrain from using negative values as it just makes things messy to bug fix.